# Get API errors from Laravel into Flutter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this code for `User Sign Up` in Laravel:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
  public function register(Request $request)
  {
          $validatedData = $request->validate([
              'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
              'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
              'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
              'phone' => 'required|unique:users',
              'type' => 'boolean',
              'verified' => 'boolean'
  ]);
  
          $user = User::create([
              'name' => $validatedData['name'],
              'email' => $validatedData['email'],
              'phone' => $validatedData['phone'],
              'type' => $validatedData['type'],
              'verified' => $validatedData['verified'],
              'password' => Hash::make($validatedData['password']),
         ]);
  
  $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->accessToken;
  
  return response()->json([
                    'user' => $user,
                    'access_token' => $token,
                     'token_type' => 'Bearer',
  ]);
  }
```

As you can see , some of my field are `unique` , so I want to display a message in my front side that displays the error from the back side.

Exemple : When a user enters a used phone number , I want to return an error saying : `this phone number has been used`  .

How can I achieve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Find record in `User` table using `phone` number, if record exists, then return `this phone number has been used`, otherwise, do something else

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `User` record from the database by phone. If the record exists, then do your logic

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
  public function register(Request $request)
  {
          $validatedData = $request->validate([
              'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
              'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
              'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
              'phone' => 'required|unique:users',
              'type' => 'boolean',
              'verified' => 'boolean'
          ]);
  
        // get a user record by phone
        $record = User::where('phone', $validatedData['phone'])->find();
        if (!empty($record)) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'this phone number has been used'
                ])
        }

         //..... 
  }
```